# Angular hide splash screen after resolve service done

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In my Angular 12 app I am using splash screen as div  inside app-root.

```
<app-root>
   <div class="splash-screen">
        
    </div>
</app-root>
```

In router module forRoot path I am calling service to resolve data before display main component.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
            {
                path: '', component: AppMainComponent,
                resolve: {userInfo: userInfoResolver},
```

In my main component I am using that data

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.route.data.subscribe(
            (data: Data) => {
                 this.userInfo=data['userInfo'];
            }
        );
    }
```

Service which fetching user Info running for few seconds, in that time splash screen is already gone and page is white without content.

My question is:
How I can hide splash screen after fetching userInfo in ngOnInit method ?
Where did I make mistake in defining splash screen or in way I prepare data for main component in resolve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use splash screen this way for showing it completely customizable -

In index.html -

```
<my-app></my-app>
<div id="splashScreen"></div>
```

Add some styles in global styles (as per requirement) -

```
#splashScreen{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: red; /* change as per need */
}
```

And then remove the splash screen from anywhere in the app -

```
      constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
    
      hideSplashScreen() {
        let splash = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#splashScreen');
        if (splash.style.display != 'none') splash.style.display = 'none';
      }
```

Working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ykr1zc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).